# Angular UI-Grid dropdown is not capturing the changes

Tags: angular-ui-grid, dropdown

I'm new to angular ui-grid.

I want to implement a dropdown box for inline editing and I follow this tutorial (gender column): http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable and I modified it by using a new cshtml page (as shown below) because I want to set the option from database instead of enter the options manually.

The code below is where I implemented the dropdown box:

```
name: app.localize('Roles'),
field: 'getRoleNames()',
minWidth: 160,
editableCellTemplate: '~/App/common/views/users/roleDropDownList.cshtml'
```

And here is the code of roleDropDownList.cshtml

```
<div ng-controller="common.views.users.index as vm">
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="role in vm.roles">{{role.displayName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now I'm able to choose the option but it's like not capturing the changes when I choose 1 of the options.

Here is the example:
[DropDown sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwZUf.png)

As you can see in the image, the row in red color means it's dirty row (edited) but the row that I edited with dropdown is not in red color means it's not being edited and it can't be save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that more easier to implement what I want.

```
name: app.localize('Roles'),
field: 'getRoleNames()',
minWidth: 160
editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
editDropdownValueLabel: 'displayName',
editDropdownIdLabel: 'displayName'
```

editDropdownValueLabel is to set the value of the options otherwise it will shows "undefined" as image shown below

[Example of dropdown undefined options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pfB5.png)

editDropdownIdLabel is to show the value of the selected option otherwise it will shows ID as image shown below

[Showed Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I79PF.png)

The code below is to get the data from database:

```
vm.userGridOptions.columnDefs[3].editDropdownOptionsArray = result.data.items;
```